# Using Fluidsynth to play notes from SoundFonts on Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, audio-streaming, midi, soundfont

Is there a way to allow android to play sounds using SoundFont files via using FluidSynth?
I've been looking at [jOrgan](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jorgan/index.php?title=Development) but the source code seems to be kind of... overwhelming to say the least.

Problem is that java sound API is not supported in android so a great sample to the project i'm in would have been [Java Sound Demo's](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/samples/JavaSoundDemo/) Midi Synth.

I think I should be fine with some porting from C to JNI but I'm not knowledgeable when it comes to handling audio features (I've only read and started researching today).

Any Help?

Also I've read the following threads and tried available java/android projects with possible solution for this:

- [Intro to the three Android Audio APIs](http://www.phonesdevelopers.info/1776983/)
- [Midi Driver](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8201)

Comment: I am think about writing wrapper on fluidsynth through jni too.

Comment: I wish there were a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.fluidsynth.org/api/example_8c-example.html

this doc tell how to load .sf2 file

and, call this to play a note

```
fluid_synth_noteon(synth, 0, key, 80);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this app. This app use libfluidsynth.so library.

[Karaoke Live MIDI Player DEMO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rardhian.livemidi.demo)