# How do I create an audio file (wav/mp3) given a midi file with my own soundbank?

Tags: android, audio, midi

I tried looking for an Android library that deals with creating audio files given a midi file (and using my own sound files) but had a hard time finding any.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336447/converting-midi-file-to-raw-audio-using-a-software-synth) SO question and checked out the links that were provided, but still, no luck. To my understanding this process is called soft synthesis.

Isn't there a way to do this programmatically?